# Disable current time in jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

i have a timepicker which is shown below

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker({
        showInputs: false,
        showMeridian: false
    });
```

I have used **class timepicker** in one of my textbox,

The actual issue is the textbox is displaying current time . i.e **18:00**, but i dont want to display it, How to empty the text box?

Comment: Please use this style:
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
    float:left;
    background: #900;
    display: none;
    }

Comment: Its timepicker not datetimepicker

Comment: have you looked into the plugin's docs to see if there is something like an option when initing which gives you control over what to show, if anything at all, on start up as a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You tried:

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker({
    setTime: null
});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code and its working proper now

```
$('body').on('focus',".timepicker", function(){    
$(".timepicker").timepicker({
        showInputs: false,
        showMeridian: false,
        setTime: null

    }); });
```